How to apply semantic tokenize on sentence in java by NLP?
Can an NLP model be used to tokenize a sentence based on its semantic meaning?
For example,
for the sentence: If the driver's age is more than 20,
the tokens would be:
Token1: if
Token2: driver age
Token3: more than
Token4: 20

The example that you have added does not make any sense to me. Can you provide the explanation for your example. And yes you can tokenize anyway you wanted. But for that to happen you have to define the systematic logic for it.
